# Centering text in table and multi column environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to center the text in a table code given below in first column only just like the other two columns  created by multi column centered the heading **Dispersion Constant (R)**. I want the **Algorithm** heading in first column of table to be centered just like the **Dispersion Constant (R)** . The result of following code is given in figure below. Keep in mind I just want **Algorithm** to be centered not the content below(SCA,MCMA,etc) the **Algorithm** Heading. Thank You. Please help?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Dispersion Constant $(R)$ Values}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\centering
\textbf{Algorithm} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Dispersion Constant $(R)$}}\\
\hline
& \textbf{M=16} & \textbf{M=32}\\ \hline

SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\\hline
MCMA & R\textsubscript{MCMA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{MCMA} = 123\\\hline 
MCMA(Dual Mode) & R\textsubscript{MCMA}& R\textsubscript{MCMA}\\\hline 
DD-MCMA & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA} = 123\\\hline 
DD-MCMA(Dual Mode) & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA}& R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA}\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithm}` might need `|` lines, not tested. No MWE.

Comment: Have you ever thought about a more professional and modern table setup? Your table reminds me of a prison in an old western movie.

Comment: No actually i m writing conference paper for IEEE and I need it for this purpose.

Comment: The \multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithm} command centered it but the vertical line gets doubled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must employ the "prison look" for tables, but wish to lessen the visual oppressiveness, consider getting rid of the `\hline` directives in the body of the `tabular` material. And, load the `array` package and set `\extrarowheight` to a small non-zero length value. :-)

You should also make an effort to give the term "R" ("dispersion value") a consistent appearance. In your code, it shows up in math italics in the table's header but in upright ("Roman") in the body of the table. Do make the appearance of this variable name consistent. In the code below, I show how to make use of the math-italics method. And, while we're talking about consistency, I've made the `M` term employ (bold) math italics as well.

Finally, to center some material in a single cell of the first column, use a `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` "wrapper".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{caption}  % for '\captionsetup' macro
\usepackage{amstext}  % for '\text' macro
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h]
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering

\caption{\boldmath Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}\\
\hline
& \boldmath $M=16$ & \boldmath $M=32$ \\ 
\hline

SCA & $R_{\text{SCA}} = 123$ & $R_{\text{SCA}} = 123$ \\ %\hline
MCMA & $R_{\text{MCMA}} = 123$ & $R_{\text{MCMA}} = 123$\\ %\hline 
MCMA(Dual Mode) & $R_{\text{MCMA}}$ & $R_{\text{MCMA}}$\\ %\hline 
DD-MCMA & $R_{\text{DD-MCMA}} = 123$ & $R_{\text{DD-MCMA}} = 123$\\%\hline 
DD-MCMA(Dual Mode) & $R_{\text{DD-MCMA}}$& $R_{\text{DD-MCMA}}$\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: faizanTabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h]%bad style
\centering
\caption{Dispersion Constant $(R)$ Values}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dispersion Constant $(R)$}}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& \textbf{M=16} & \textbf{M=32}\\ 

SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\
MCMA & R\textsubscript{MCMA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{MCMA} = 123\\ 
MCMA(Dual Mode) & R\textsubscript{MCMA}& R\textsubscript{MCMA}\\ 
DD-MCMA & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA} = 123\\ 
DD-MCMA(Dual Mode) & R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA}& R\textsubscript{DD-MCMA}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```