# multi-column title centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, format

I know that there are multiple questions regarding similar problems, but I've tried multiple offered solutions and I just can't get anything to work.

When using \hskip in my table, the titles (Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, etc.) are extremely off-center. How can I make sure the titles  are centred to the row?

[image: My table]

Code below for the heading:

```
\centering
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 0.3in}cc@{\hskip 0.3in}cc@{\hskip 0.3in}cc@{\hskip 0.3in}cc@{\hskip 0.3in}cc} 
\toprule

&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Bitcoin}}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Bitcoin Cash}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Ethereum}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Litecoin}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Zcash}}} \\ 

& Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible  \\
\midrule


\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `hskip`? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mane32 To allow for space between the columns - so that those red cell colours don't touch at all

Comment: I would have followed a different approach for your table but you can use `\hspace*{0.3in}Bitcoin` to cancel your `hskip`

Comment: You'd have to add the extra `\hskip` also to the declaration of the `\multicolumn` column ([similar to vertical rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439836/277964)). But IMHO even in combination with color the extra space it not helpful. Extra wide spacing always make the readability worse.

Comment: BTW: *Never* scale a tabular! Scaling is the death of typography and readability!

Answer (score 0):

if you use `NiceMatrix`?:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\scalebox{.75}{
\begin{NiceTabular}[c]{lcccccccccc}
  \CodeBefore
        \rectanglecolor{gray!50}{3-2}{4-3}
        \rectanglecolor{gray!30}{3-4}{4-5}
        \cellcolor{gray!20}{3-6,3-7}
    \Body
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Bitcoin}}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Bitcoin Cash}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Ethereum}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Litecoin}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Zcash}}} \\ 

    & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible  \\
    \midrule
    Jan 1, 2019 & 4 & 3-4 & & & & & & & & \\
    Jan 1, 2019 & 4 & 3-4 & & & & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at hand, it just uses different colours, which would've been possible with `tabular` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this, instead of using `@{\hspace{<some-length>}` use a suitably formatted extra column. The side effect is that you need to input `&&` everywhere you're using such a space-column.

In the following I also used some shortcuts to have less issues with typing stuff. Notably:

- The `\space`-column type, which you should leave just empty. It injects a bit of space (in my definition `5pt`, the `-2\tabcolsep` are there to compensate those (basically turns the column into being `@{}c<{\hskip5pt}@{}`, but without LaTeX actually thinking they would be `@{}`, so that the cell colour has the correct borders).
- Who wants to put `\cellcolor{<color>}` all over the place? So I defined `\hlCell`.
- `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` becomes tedious as well... `\myhead` is simpler.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}

\newcommand*\myhead[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcolumntype\space{c<{\hskip\dimexpr5pt-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\newcommand*\hlCell{\cellcolor{red!50!white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c*{5}{\space cc}}
\toprule
  && \myhead{Bitcoin}    && \myhead{Bitcoin Cash} && \myhead{Ethereum}
    && \myhead{Litecoin}   && \myhead{Zcash} \\
  && Reported & Possible && Reported & Possible   && Reported & Possible
    && Reported & Possible && Reported & Possible \\
\midrule
  Jan 1, 2019 && \hlCell 4 & \hlCell 3-4 && \hlCell 2 & \hlCell 1-2
    && \hlCell 3 & \hlCell 2-3 && 3 & 3 && 2 & 2 \\
  Jan 2, 2019 && \hlCell 4 & \hlCell 3-4 && \hlCell 2 & \hlCell 1-2
    && 3 & 2-3 && 3 & 3 && 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If that table doesn't fit your margin, don't use `\adjustbox` or similar, instead the three easiest things to do is: Reduce `\tabcolsep`, use `@{}` at either end of the columns (so remove the outer most padding), and reduce the fontsize using a fontsize command (for instance `\small` or `\footnotesize`).

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can add `@{\hspace{2cm}` between two columns `c` in the preamble with the expected output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[create-extra-nodes]{lcc@{\hspace{2cm}}cccccccc}
    \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
      \tikz \node [ fill = red!15 , fit = (3-2-medium) (4-3-medium) ] { } ;
      \tikz \node [ fill = red!15 , fit = (3-4-medium) (4-5-medium) ] { } ;
    \Body
    \toprule
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    &\Block{1-2}{Bitcoin}&&\Block{1-2}{Bitcoin Cash} && \Block{1-2}{Ethereum} && \Block{1-2}{Litecoin} && \Block{1-2}{Zcash} \\ 

    & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible & Reported & Possible  \\
    \midrule
    Jan 1, 2019 & 4 & 3-4 & & & & & & & & \\
    Jan 1, 2019 & 4 & 3-4 & & & & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]